# Test result of assignment against original value without introducing extra variable in ANSI C

Tags: c

I wonder if I can at the same time assign a value and check if it changed in a C conditional expression without introducing new examples. Consider the function `test` as fixed in the following example (I don't want to change its parameters or return values). I search for a variation of the conditional in the `main` routine which prints `"works"` because the value of `n` is incremented by 1 by the test routine. I.e. I want a comparison with the old value of nsing. At the same time it should print `"works not"` if `n` would not be incremented by test. I wonder if this could be possible exploiting rules for the order of evaluation or something, i.e. without introducing new variables which store the value of `n`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int test(int n)
{    
    return n + 1;    
}

int main()
{    
  int n;

  if ((n = test(n)) == n) {
     printf("works not\n");
  } else {
     printf("works\n");
  }

  return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Why would the function fail, i. e. not return n + 1?

Comment: Oh not again sequence points please...!!

Comment: test is a (too) trivial replacement for a complicated function whos return value I cannot predict.

Comment: @Mr.32 Didn't find it because I didn't know what to search for!

Comment: How, conceptually, could you test against the original value without saving the original value? It seems like you're either asking for something that's obviously impossible or not clearly explaining what it is you find wrong with the obvious solution.

Comment: @David Schwartz It is because I do not know how the machine performs the comparison internally. It could e.g. first evaluate the rhs (`n`), store the result in a register (i.e. make a copy of the old value internally) and then evaluate the lhs, and compare its result to the stored rhs result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that and that's undefined behaviour, because there's no sequence point between the assignment and the comparison.

Comment: In the above example `(n=test(n))==n-1` would actually work but I search for the general case where I don't know by how much `n` can change ...

Comment: @highsciguy, that special case works completely out of luck. You cannot count on it as it may change if you change your compiler.

Comment: @highsciguy: It's undefined behaviour, and the words "it works" don't apply. They're meaningless.

Comment: Actually, the real problem is that there's no sequence point between the assignment to n and the read of n that goes to the comparison -- the comparison itself must always be after the assignment (due to dependency)

Answer (score 1):

short answer: no you cannot. For a longer explanation have a look at [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point)